# Excel Userform to Select Start and End Dates and Fill in Table with dates in between

Tags: excel, vba, calendar, userform

I created a Userform that takes input of an event, and adds that data to the first blank row in column C of a table.

The userform has inputs for a Start Date and End Date. The code below adds 1 row of data to the table with the start date and the corresponding info.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("2019 Events")

LastRow = ws.Range("C6").End(xlDown).Row + 1 ' Finds the first blank row Column C

ws.Range("C" & LastRow).Value = start_date.Value
ws.Range("D" & LastRow).Value = audit_types.Value
ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Value = event_names.Value
ws.Range("G" & LastRow).Value = Site_names.Value
ws.Range("J" & LastRow).Value = names1.Value
ws.Range("K" & LastRow).Value = Names2.Value
ws.Range("M" & LastRow).Value = notes.Value

Unload UserForm1

End Sub
```

***My goal is when a user inputs a Start and End Date, the userform populates a line entry on the table for each date between the start and end, with the rest of the data from the form the same on all rows.***

For example, if the Start Date is 12/01/2019 and End Date is 12/03/2019, the userform should add 3 lines of data to the table, where 3 rows in Column C are 12/01/2019, 12/02/2019, and 12/02/2019 and the rest of the rows are duplicates from the other values on the table.

The idea is to populate a list of events and their info, but each date needs it's own line item even if a single event covers multiple days.

Comment: Since that is a good goal, but SO is not meant to be a code-writing service, can you [edit] your question with what you yourself have tried to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

> Work out the difference between start and end dates once entered, then loop your code that amount of times, each time going to the next row and adding one day onto the date from the row above it.
>
> For example: Start date = 1st Jan End Date = 5th Jan Difference = 4 Loop code 5 times (4 + 1 so as to include the end date as the final row)
>
> If use input the Start Date into cell B2, End Date into B3 then the information into C3 then the below code would work. The concept would be exactly the same if using a UserForm, just update the lines where you define the StartDate etc variable.

```
Sub Dates()

Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim NumberRows As Long
Dim L As Long
Dim DataInput As String

StartDate = [B1].Value
EndDate = [B2].Value
DataInput = [B3].Value
NumberRows = EndDate - StartDate + 1

'Populate first row
[A6].Value = StartDate
[B6].Value = DataInput

'Populate subsequent rows
L = 1

    Do Until L = NumberRows
    
    Range("A" & L + 6).Value = Range("A" & L + 5).Value + 1
    Range("B" & L + 6).Value = DataInput
    
    L = L + 1
    
    Loop

End Sub
```